# How to use toggle with a parent class

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am studying JavaScript during my internship and my boss asked me to : could you try to do this again, but put a class on the parent div, rather than on each Rect?
does that mean that I have to use parent-class to do the same work ? Because i have been trying since this morning and i cannot figure it out how to do.

my code is good with child class :

```
const rect2 = document.getElementById("rect2"); // On récupère le rectangle 2

const allRects = document.getElementsByClassName("rect");

rect2.addEventListener("click", makeAllRectsSmaller);

function makeAllRectsSmaller() {
  for (let index = 0; index < allRects.length; index++) {
    // console.log(allRects[index]);

    isBig = allRects[index].classList.contains("bigRect");
    // console.log(isBig);

    if (isBig) {
      console.log(isBig);

      allRects[index].classList.remove("bigRect");
      allRects[index].classList.add("smallRect");
      // console.log(allRects[index]);
    } else {
      // Sinon
      allRects[index].classList.remove("smallRect");
      allRects[index].classList.add("bigRect");
      console.log(allRects[index]);
    }
  }

  // console.log(allRects);
}
```

My style and body are like this

```
<style>
  .rect {
    background: grey;
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
  }
  
  .rect.red {
    background: red;
  }
  
  .rect.blue {
    background: blue;
  }
  
  .rect.bigRect {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  
  .rect.smallRect {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="rectjs" class="exoJs">
    <div id="rect1" class="rect red bigRect"></div>
    <div id="rect2" class="rect red bigRect"></div>
    <div id="rect3" class="rect red bigRect"></div>
  </div>
```

But i cannot find a way to use parent class instead of child class.

Is someone could help me please ? thank you very much

Comment: What should the script do? Toggle the big and small classes whenever `rect2` is clicked? Or should all rectangles react to the click?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. Clicking on the second rectangle will reduce the size of the three Rects (and clicking on the third rect will reset everything to the original).

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this in your CSS:

```
.exoJs div {
    /* your CSS  */
}
```

This targets the rect `div`s inside of the parent `div` (`.exoJs`).

Comment: Thank you very much for this help.  Could I also ask if there are any changes to be made in the code with .exoJs ? thank you for your time.

Comment: No other changes are need for this to work. You can essentially just replace every instance of `.rect` with `.exoJs div`.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the the `bigRect` class on the `#rectjs` element. There is not a lot of need to have 3 classes (`rect`, `smallRect` and `bigRect`) if some of them have similar styles. Instead make the rects small by default and only toggle `bigRect`.

```
const rect2 = document.getElementById("rect2");
const rectjs = document.getElementById("rectjs");
rect2.addEventListener("click", makeAllRectsSmaller);

function makeAllRectsSmaller() {
  rectjs.classList.toggle('bigRect');
}
```

Then apply your styles like this. `.rect` is the base of the style, the colors can modify each rect. But `bigRect` is now on the `.exoJS` class, and when it is, all `.rect` elements that are it's descendant, should be big.

```
.rect {
  background: grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.rect.red {
  background: red;
}
  
.rect.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.exoJs.bigRect .rect {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```